# How to use javascript external library files in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am new in Reactjs. I am integrating admin theme that contain JS libraries like graph,tooltip etc. I am facing issue it produce errors and also dropdown not working.
My **index.html** file is with js files

```
<script src="./assets/js/main/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/main/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/plugins/loaders/blockui.min.js"></script>
<!-- /core JS files -->
<!-- Theme JS files -->
<script src="./global_assets/js/plugins/visualization/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/plugins/visualization/d3/d3_tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/plugins/forms/styling/switchery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/plugins/ui/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/plugins/pickers/daterangepicker.js"></script>

<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/demo_pages/dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/demo_charts/pages/dashboard/light/streamgraph.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/demo_charts/pages/dashboard/light/sparklines.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/demo_charts/pages/dashboard/light/lines.js"></script>   
<script src="./global_assets/js/demo_charts/pages/dashboard/light/areas.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/demo_charts/pages/dashboard/light/donuts.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/demo_charts/pages/dashboard/light/bars.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/demo_charts/pages/dashboard/light/progress.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/demo_charts/pages/dashboard/light/heatmaps.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/demo_charts/pages/dashboard/light/pies.js"></script>
<script src="./global_assets/js/demo_charts/pages/dashboard/light/bullets.js"></script>
<!-- /theme JS files -->
```

and  i am getting these issues
[image]
and also dropdown not working how I can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm packages for the same.

1. [react-d3-graph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-d3-graph) for d3 graphs
2. [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) for moment
3. [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) for date picker

Install npm packages using `npm install` command

Import them on your React Component whenever you want to use them using `import` command

```
import moment from 'moment';
import { Graph } from "react-d3-graph";
```

Check documentation of packages before implementing the same.

Comment: let me know in case you are still facing any issue